# Website created by Flex Builder works on every browser that use flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, adobe, flexbuilder

Does websites created by Flex Builder works on every browsers that use Flash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The web site created by Flex Builder requires Flash player version 9 or above.

[FAQ: Flex and Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/faq/#section-5)

Comment: @xRobot: Yes, as far as I can gather.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, Flex Builder generates a flash swf file of your application.  It is a flash file and therefore will play on any appropiate flash player (v9 or above).  Flex is just the name for the marriage between the MXML markup and Actionscript 3 language, while flash is the compiled output.